# Python call to JIRA Rest Api search not returning Created (Date) or Resolution fields

Tags: python, json, jira, jira-rest-api

Testing out using python to make a rest api call to pull defects/bugs from my jira instance. Using the code provided in the [api_docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/), I put together this query:

```
payload = json.dumps( {
 
  "jql": "issuetype in (Bug,Defect) AND CreatedDate >= 2021\\u002f01\\u002f01",
  "maxResults": 1,
  #"fieldsByKeys": false,
  "fields": [
   "summary",
   "assignee",
   "reporter",
   "status",
   "resolution"
   "created",
   "updated"
  ],
  "startAt": 0
} )
```

The call is successful, except it returns every field but `created` and `resolution`. I used `/rest/api/3/field` to ensure that the field was spelled correctly and it was. Also tried capitalizing `Created`.

```
{
    "id": "created",
    "name": "Created",
    "custom": false,
    "orderable": false,
    "navigable": true,
    "searchable": true,
    "clauseNames": ["created",
    "createdDate"],
    "schema": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "system": "created"
    }
}
```

API output example:

```
{
    "expand": "names,schema",
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "fields": {
                "assignee": null,
                "reporter": example,
                "status": example,
                "summary": "DEFECT: Test 1",
                "updated": "2021-03-07T11:14:31.000-0500"
            },
            "id": "123456",
            "key": "Example-4",
            "self": "example_link"
        }
    ],
    "maxResults": 1,
    "startAt": 0,
    "total": 100
}
```

Alternatively, when I leave `fields` blank I do get all the fields including `created` and `resolution`. However, I don't want to do that as we have hundreds of custom fields that get pulled in as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a typo in your code sample. You are missing the comma after the *resolution* field. You code should be:

```
payload = json.dumps( {
 
  "jql": "issuetype in (Bug,Defect) AND CreatedDate >= 2021\\u002f01\\u002f01",
  "maxResults": 1,
  "fields": [
   "summary",
   "assignee",
   "reporter",
   "status",
   "resolution", # Note the comma here
   "created",
   "updated"
  ],
  "startAt": 0
} )
```

Comment: Brilliant, this of course was the problem. Thank you!